# SonarQube error while analyzing code with binary literals

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I want to use SonarQube to analyse my project which is built on Jenkins. In my project I have some literals written in binary system (e.g. 0b00001111).

When I'm trying to do an analysis, I am obtaining fallowing **error**:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project org: 
SonarQube is unable to analyze file : 'whatever': For input string: "b00001111" -> [Help 1]
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b00001111"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:776)
at java.lang.Long.decode(Long.java:928)
at org.sonar.java.checks.SillyBitOperationCheck.evaluateExpression(SillyBitOperationCheck.java:101)
....
```

**Versioning informations:**

SonarQube Jenkins plugin version: 2.2.1

SonarQube version: 5.1

SonarQube maven Plugin version: 2.5/2.6 (I've tried both of them)

In project I am using JDK 1.8. I don't know how to check if SonarQube is using also 1.8, but I've choosen "Inherit from Project" in SonarQube configuration panel in Jenkins.

Comment: Can you provide also provide the version of the Java plugin you are using? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating the java plugin to 3.5

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: it might answer the question, as I was having the same problem and could solve this by updating the Java Plugin.