# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b10000000"

Tags: sonarqube

I have SonarQube 5.1.2 with sonar ant task 2.3.

I have the following line in the source file

```
if((~b & 0b10000000) > 0)
```

Running sonar on this source file returns in

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b10000000"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
>       at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:776)
>       at java.lang.Long.decode(Long.java:928)
>       at org.sonar.java.checks.SillyBitOperationCheck.evaluateExpression(SillyBitOperationCheck.java:101)
>       at org.sonar.java.checks.SillyBitOperationCheck.visitNode(SillyBitOperationCheck.java:66)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:95)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:113)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:97)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:73)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:67)
>       at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:122)
>       at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.walkAndVisit(AstWalker.java:67)
>       at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:107)
>       ... 53 more
>   Why is this happening ? It seems that SonarQube is not reading 0b10000000 and is omitting the first 0.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this or ?

Thanks

Comment: It would be a hack, but does it work if you put 128 (i.e.the decimal equivalent)?

Comment: Same problem over at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574009/sonarqube-error-while-analyzing-code-with-binary-literals

Answer (score 0):

That's a (relatively new, Java 7) binary literal.

I think you need to upgrade your Sonar to a newer version that can deal with it.

If this is source code you control, you could also avoid binary literals and replace them with "classical" ones, such as `0x80` here (but maybe an outdated Sonar will also stumble over a few other things, there is a lot new syntax in Java 8).

Comment: I use the most current version of sonar. but thanks for the other link. I will follow up there

Comment: Please upgrade to latest version of sonar java plugin. (and precise which one you are using on your question)